# COUNT and percentage two value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, math, count, average

I have a visitor table with this fields:

```
id|---|browser|---|ip|---|device|---|city|---|state|---|country|---|status
```

Was trying to show most visited device using morris.js Donut. It requires a percentage value to show as percentage. I was trying to fetch the data from MySQL as calculated value.

```
SELECT device,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM visitor WHERE status = '1') as total,
COUNT(id) as visit FROM visitor WHERE status = '1' GROUP BY device
```

The value I am trying to get is:

```
device|---|visit|---|percentage
iOS|---|2|---|40
Android|---|2|---|40
Windows|---|1|---|20
```

So the query will count total all visitor before grouping the into particular devices. Then calculate percentage of per device.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  v.device, COUNT(*) visit, COUNT(*) / total percentage
FROM    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) total
        FROM    visitor
        WHERE   status = 1
        ) t
JOIN    visitor v
ON      status = 1
GROUP BY
        v.device
```

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
select a.device, b.total, c.percent from visitor
    left join  (select device, count(id) as total from visitor where status='1') as b on b.device=a.device
    left join ( select device, b.total/count(id) as percent from visitor where status='1') on c.device=a.device
    group by device
```